# Makefile - include files not found when building with multiple source files

Tags: makefile, mingw

I have a make file:

```
# Makefile
CC = gcc
SRC = pixel.c
TARGET = pixel.exe
OBJECTS = bmp.o pixel.o
#CFLAGS_W = -Wall -Wl,-subsystem,windows
CFLAGS_W = -Wall
LFLAGS_W = -lSDL2
INCS_W = -I.\SDL2\include
LIBS_W = -L.\SDL2\lib\x64

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(INCS_W) $(LIBS_W) $(CFLAGS_W) $(LFLAGS_W) -g -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

it will build `bmp.c`, but when it tries to build `pixel.c` I get the error:

`pixel.c:6:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory`

however, `pixel.c` has been building fine all the time I was just building it on its own (before I added `bmp.c`), using the command:

```
all:
    $(CC) $(SRC) $(INCS_W) $(LIBS_W) $(CFLAGS_W) $(LFLAGS_W) -g -o $(TARGET)
```

I really struggle with makefiles because I just don't use them enough, but this doesn't really feel like a "make" problem.

I'm using mingw32-make and gcc in a windows sandbox.

EDIT:

I have added

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INCS_W) $(LIBS_W) $(CFLAGS_W) $(LFLAGS_W) -g -c $< -o $@
```

to my makefile, which gets me a step further (I think), but now complains that all of the SDL functions are undefined

```
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\Projects\Pixel>mingw32-make
gcc -I./SDL2/include -L./SDL2/lib/x64 -Wall -lSDL2 -g -c bmp.c -o bmp.o
gcc -I./SDL2/include -L./SDL2/lib/x64 -Wall -lSDL2 -g -c pixel.c -o pixel.o
gcc -I./SDL2/include -L./SDL2/lib/x64 -Wall -lSDL2 -g -o pixel.exe bmp.o pixel.o
pixel.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\Projects\Pixel/pixel.c:119: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\Projects\Pixel/pixel.c:121: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\Projects\Pixel/pixel.c:126: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\Projects\Pixel/pixel.c:131: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
...
```

I *can* get the whole project to compile if I just do this on its own:

```
SRC = bmp.c pixel.c
...
test:
    $(CC) $(SRC) $(INCS_W) $(LIBS_W) $(CFLAGS_W) $(LFLAGS_W) -g -o $(TARGET)
```

which is fine, it'll do, but it rebuilds everything every time, and I'd like to know why it isn't working anyway :)

Comment: You should use forward-slashes in pathnames when dealing with make, or with other POSIX-derived programs like POSIX shell and GCC.

Comment: @MadScientist sure, although I'm running make from a regular cmd.exe window, and get lovely errors like `C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\Projects\Pixel/pixel.c:119: undefined reference to SDL_Init` so I don't think windows 10 really cares about slash direction these days ;)

Comment: Windows doesn't.  But POSIX tools, like the POSIX shell (and make, depending on how it was compiled) etc. definitely _do_ care.  That's why it's best to use forward slashes since they work in both environments (except for some cmd.exe built-ins like `dir` etc.) while backward-slashes only work with Windows tools.

Comment: Anyway, that error you're showing means now the compiler can find the header file, which is what you wanted.  If the code still doesn't compile that's a different issue.

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, I've been playing with it to try and work out why it's not working right. I can get it to the next step by adding another rule to the file, but it's still not compiling - well, looks like it's not linking properly. I'm not 100% sure.